# Fill NA and update columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to conditionally fill the missing and update the value from another dataframe.

I want to fill missing and update the data on column *values* in dataframe **smalldf**.

The condition is, if the value in *B* column  (**large df**) is in the range of columns *Range_FROM  and Range_TO in (**small df**)*. Always choose the minimum records in (**largedf**) to fill or update the *values* in **smalldf**.

- For example, in the second record of smalldf *values* (3), as there is a smaller value (1.3) in the largedf, it would end up being updated by a smaller value (1.3).
- Another example, the third record of smalldf (Nan) is being filled by 1.6, as it is the smallest value within the range of Range_FROM (1.5) and Range_TO (1.6)

##### This is the first dataframe (**smalldf**):

| RoadNo | Range_FROM | Range_TO | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | 1.15 | 1.2 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.35 | 1.4 | 3 |
| A001 | 1.55 | 1.6 | Nan |
| A001 | 1.75 | 1.8 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.9 | 2 | Nan |

##### This is the second dataframe (**largedf**):

| RoadNo | B | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | 1.1 | 0.2 |
| A001 | 1.2 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.3 | 1.9 |
| A001 | 1.4 | 1.3 |
| A001 | 1.5 | 1.6 |
| A001 | 1.6 | 1.9 |
| A001 | 1.7 | 0.2 |
| A001 | 1.8 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.9 | 1.9 |
| A001 | 2 | 1.3 |

##### Below is the expected dataframe:

| RoadNo | Range_FROM | Range_TO | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | 1.15 | 1.2 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.35 | 1.4 | 1.3 |
| A001 | 1.55 | 1.6 | 1.6 |
| A001 | 1.75 | 1.8 | 0.1 |
| A001 | 1.9 | 2 | 1.3 |

##### Below is the code to create the two dataframes:

```
smalldf = pd.DataFrame(data={"RoadNo":["A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001"],   
                             "Range_FROM": [1.15, 1.35, 1.55, 1.75, 1.9], 
                             "Range_TO":[1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2],
                             "values": [0.1, 0.25, "Nan", 0.1, "Nan" ]})
                             

largedf = pd.DataFrame(data={"RoadNo":["A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A001"],   
                             "B": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2],                             
                             "values": [0.2, 0.1, 1.9, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 0.2, 0.1, 1.9, 1.3]})
```

Please keep in mind that there are other RoadNo (e.g. A002, A003).

Both left join and fillna(df) in pandas did not produce my desired result. Is there a function in Pandas or SQL that can help me with this operation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the third value has a range from 1.55 to 1.6, and 1.5 in larger table doesn't fall in this range. to get 1.6 as you indicated.

Comment: I added a SQL-like version of the answer that gets your exact desired output~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL your problem would look like:

```sql
SELECT df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO, MIN(df2.values)
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 
    ON df1.RoadNo = df2.RoadNo
    AND df2.B >= df1.Range_FROM
    AND df2.B <= df1.Range_TO
GROUP BY df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO
```

So we can do:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q = '''SELECT df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO, MIN(df2."values") AS "values"
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 
    ON df1.RoadNo = df2.RoadNo
    AND df2.B > df1.Range_LAG
    AND df2.B <= df1.Range_TO
GROUP BY df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO'''
pysqldf(q)
df = pysqldf(q)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  RoadNo  Range_FROM  Range_TO  values
0   A001        1.15       1.2     0.1
1   A001        1.35       1.4     1.3
2   A001        1.55       1.6     1.9
3   A001        1.75       1.8     0.1
4   A001        1.90       2.0     1.3
```

---

But since you actually want something a little different, let's try:

```
df1['Range_LAG'] = df1.Range_TO.shift(fill_value=0)

q = '''SELECT df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO, MIN(df2."values") AS "values"
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 
    ON df1.RoadNo = df2.RoadNo
    AND df2.B > df1.Range_LAG
    AND df2.B <= df1.Range_TO
GROUP BY df1.RoadNo, df1.Range_FROM, df1.Range_TO'''

df = pysqldf(q)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  RoadNo  Range_FROM  Range_TO  values
0   A001        1.15       1.2     0.1
1   A001        1.35       1.4     1.3
2   A001        1.55       1.6     1.6
3   A001        1.75       1.8     0.1
4   A001        1.90       2.0     1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it
Merge the two DF based on the RoadNo and then filter out the ones that meet the criteria. finally update the values where they are null with the new value

value of Nan in the df is assumed to be NaN, but had a typo in question.
if it is indeed a Nan, you can convert that to NaN as follows after the merge that created df3 dataframe

```
df3['values'] = df3['values'].replace('Nan',np.nan ).astype(float)
```

```
df3=df.merge(df2, on='RoadNo', how='left', suffixes=('','_y')).query('(B >=Range_FROM) & (B<= Range_TO)')

df3['values'] = np.where((df3['values'].isnull()) | (df3['values'] > df3['values_y']) , df3['values_y'], df3['values'])
df3.drop(columns=['B','values_y'])
```

```
    RoadNo  Range_FROM  Range_TO    values
1   A001    1.15    1.2     0.1
13  A001    1.35    1.4     1.3
25  A001    1.55    1.6     1.9
37  A001    1.75    1.8     0.1
48  A001    1.90    2.0     1.9
49  A001    1.90    2.0     1.3
```

Comment: I got this issue: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' at line df3['values'] = np.where((df3['values'].isnull()) | (df3['values'] > df3['values_y']) , df3['values_y'], df3['values'])

Comment: I did made Nan as **NaN**, so it get recognized as Null. Can you try with NaN? I assumed it was a typo. Other than this change, I used your data and that is what I showed in result

Comment: you can convert to float as follows, I updated the answer as well    df3['values'] = df3['values'].replace('Nan',np.nan ).astype(float)